Caching compressed responses in ASP.NET Core MVC
I'm building an ASP.NET Core MVC application. I'd like to handle caching and compression in a custom way. First of all, I'd like to use my own cache implementation (as opposed to MS's own cache or the Redis cache), and to manually generate cache keys based on the request. Secondly, I'd like to cache compressed responses. That is, I'd like to have the logic in my application work roughly as follows:

Receive the request

Handle authorization/authentication

Construct a POCO object representing the request

Create the custom cache key based on this object, as well as the ETag provided by the browser

Do we already have a cached compressed response for this cache key, using the compression format requested by the user's browser? If so, return it as the response, and we're done

Otherwise, invoke the MVC controller as usual

Handle any errors

Take the result object returned by the controller, serialize it to JSON

Create the full compressed response based on this data, including the ETag header

Cache it, and return it to the user; the binary stream returned to the browser here is identical to the one we would've gotten on a cache hit in Step (5)


It seems like I should be able to do this using Output Caching:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/output?view=aspnetcore-8.0
Unfortunately, I just can't figure out the correct way to plug my code into the pipeline -- and it seems like there should be one, but no matter what I try, I am running into problems on either one end or the other...

According to your description, it is difficult for community members to provide you with testing steps or tutorials from beginning to end.

You can share the relevant codes you have tried so far and the problems you encountered, and clearly tell everyone the expected results you want and the current phenomena you encounter. Thanks
